# Protected Local Branch to avoid deletion from with visual studio (2019)

Tags: visual-studio, github, branch

In github or visual studio - how am I able to protect a local branch so it is not possible to delete?

I have an example below:
[2 local branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na1P4.png)

It is common we cherry pick code from 1 branch to another. At the point of selecting "View History" to cherry pick a commit, if by accident I was to click "Delete" the branch "testing" would be deleted. Is there a way to add a rule or restrict deletion of local branches.

I have tried and this is not the same as protecting a branch on the remote repo (adding a rule pattern etc etc) I am only interested in stopping the deletion of the local branch not the remote.

Update: So I am looking for a pre-delete hook on git, which I don't think exists. I am not sure if I can actually use the pre-commit hook to do something like:

If branch name "testing" & Trying to delete branch

- stop delete
- echo "some warning"
- exit 1

Anyone done something similar?

Comment: You can implement a hook that prevents deletion of certain branches, but typically you would configure that on the server (github) only. On github, search for "protect branch".

Comment: Its not the Protected Branches on github where you can protect remote branches.

I am after a hook or something that will stop the deletion of a local branch. From my screen shot, within visual studio its very easy (and doesn't warn you) when you delete a local branch. Is there a hook or maybe a setting in VS that can handle this?

Comment: I'm no git-hooks expert, but you can create hooks for about anything, as far as I know. Note that you can undo an accidental deletion of a local branch with the `git rev-list` command (or the corresponding TortoiseGit window)

Comment: Thank you, I will try and look into the hooks a little more to prevent this as well as test deleting a local branch and using the get rev-list.